# Counting alternating numbers in an array

Tags: c#, algorithm

Given an array of integers...

```
var numbers = new int[] { 1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,2,2,1,2,1 };
```

I need to determine a the maximum sequence of numbers that alternate up then down or down then up.

Not sure the best way to approach this, the process psuedo wise strikes me as simple but materializing code for it is evading me.

The key is the fact we are looking for max sequence, so while the above numbers could be interpreted in many ways, like a sequence of seven up-down-up and seven down-up-down the important fact is starting with the first number there is a down-up-down sequence that is 14 long.

Also I should not that we count the first item, 121 is a sequence of length 3, one could argue the sequence doesn't begin until the second digit but lets not split hairs.

Comment: Your Question is too vague. Show in more detail What you would like to do.

Comment: Sounds like max increasing sub-sequence, only check for alternate instead of increasing.

Comment: Is it always 1s and 2s? Do you need to know the start position of the streak, or just the max size?

Comment: and do they always differ by 1?

Comment: No, it can be vastly different than 1 and 2, I just wanted a simple example to avoid noise.

Comment: @James - max size is all I care to know

Comment: @Dylan - not sure how I am being vague as the gist of the question is how can one determine the highest count of numbers that consecutively alternate up/down.

Logically you can loop over this and test but each way I approached it got hairy real quick so I thought I would toss it out and see if someone had a better way.

Comment: @keithwarren7 i believe my answer is what you are looking for. it tracks the alternate up/down's both directions down-up-down and up-down-up.

Comment: Additional examples of input with expected result would go a long way toward clarifying what you mean here.  For example {1,3,2,4} alternates directions but not values, and it's not clear from your statement whether this is a case you want.

Comment: @keithwarren7 if you count manually the alternates you want counted in that sequence you used as an example do you get 7 up-down-up and 7 down-up-downs?

Comment: Made some edits to the original question to hopefully clarify intent a bit.

Comment: `{1, 2}` would return 2, but what would `{1}` return? Since the question is the size of the max sequence of numbers that alternate, a sequence with only 1 element (or a sequence of numbers that are equal eg `{1, 1, 1}`) doesn't alternate so I assume 0.

Answer (score 4):

This seems to work, it assumes that the length of numbers is greater than 4 (that case should be trivial anyways):

```
var numbers = new int[] { 1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,2,2,1,2,1 };
int count = 2, max = 0;
for (int i = 1; i < numbers.Length - 1; i++)
{

    if ((numbers[i - 1] < numbers[i] && numbers[i + 1] < numbers[i]) ||
                    (numbers[i - 1] > numbers[i] && numbers[i + 1] > numbers[i]))
    {
        count++;
        max = Math.Max(count, max);
    }
    else if ((numbers[i - 1] < numbers[i]) || (numbers[i - 1] > numbers[i])
                || ((numbers[i] < numbers[i + 1]) || (numbers[i] > numbers[i + 1])))
    {
        max = Math.Max(max, 2);
        count = 2;
    }
}
Console.WriteLine(max); // 14
```

Comment: There are 14 items in the largest sequence.

Comment: @AbeMiessler Whoops, you're right: I forgot to count the last item, corrected now.

Comment: Those "off by one"s will sneak up on you

Comment: @drch That's because it assumes the length of numbers is greater than 4, less than that and you can trivially figure it out. Not sure if that typo was DV worthy but thanks.

Comment: { 1, 2, 2, 2, 1 } return 0 as well.

Comment: @drch Yes, that's because the approach I gave looks for a sequence of more than just 2, the OP asked for an *approach* to the problem and I provided one. If you want to nit pick go ahead.

Comment: @drch Maybe it works now for every case, in any case, the right answer to a question on SO is not always providing a fully debugged, working solution. *Especially* when the OP asks for *an approach* and **not** the result, it is good to give them a means to solve their issue on their own.

Comment: I think an approach would probably be more verbose to describe the thought-process. I mean, I can see long conditional statements but then it's like "why those specific cases?"

Answer (score 2):

I'm not from a pc with a compiler right now, so I just give a try:

```
int max = 0;
int aux =0;
for(int i = 2 ; i < length; ++i)
{
    if (!((numbers[i - 2] > numbers[i - 1] && numbers[i - 1] < numbers[i]) ||
           numbers[i - 2] < numbers[i - 1] && numbers[i - 1] > numbers[i]))
    {
        aux = i - 2;
    }
    max = Math.Max(i - aux,max);
}
if (max > 0 && aux >0)
    ++max;
```

Note: should works for sequence of at least 3 elements.

Comment: @NominSim: could you clarify your objection? I mean, I'm not checking for 1 or 2 explicitly..what am I missing? Sorry but I can't test it right now..maybe better if I remove the answer but the question was nice :)

Comment: @NominSim: oh thanks.. now I understand.. I'll fix the condition then.

Comment: `{ 2, 2, 1, 2, 1 }` this returned 3, though the largest sequence is `2, 1, 2, 1`. I'm still trying to understand the logic though since it's a nice compact solution rather than checking a dozen cases.

Comment: @Keikoku: thanks for the suggestion. It was a bug, but yesterday I didn't have a compiler, so was hard to find it. I edited the post, now should work.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I thought of it

- First, you need to know whether you're starting high or starting low. eg: `1-2-1` or `2-1-2`. You might not even have an alternating pair.
- Then, you consider each number afterwards to see if it belongs in the sequence, taking into consideration the current direction.
- Everytime the sequence breaks, you need to start again by checking the direction.

I am not sure if it is possible that out of the numbers you have already seen, picking a different starting number can POSSIBLY generate a longer sequence. Maybe there is a theorem that shows it is not possible; maybe it is obvious and I am over-thinking. But I don't think it is possible since the reason why a sequence is broken is because you have two high's or two low's and there is no way around this.

I assumed the following cases

- `{}` - no elements, returns 0
- `{1}` - single element, returns 0
- `{1, 1, 1}` - no alternating sequence, returns 0

No restriction on the input beyond what C# expects. It could probably be condensed. Not sure if there is a way to capture the direction-change logic without explicitly keeping track of the direction.

```
static int max_alternate(int[] numbers)
{
  int maxCount = 0;
  int count = 0;
  int dir = 0; // whether we're going up or down

  for (int j = 1; j < numbers.Length; j++)
  {
      // don't know direction yet
      if (dir == 0)
      {
          if (numbers[j] > numbers[j-1])
          {
              count += 2; // include first number
              dir = 1; // start low, up to high
          }
          else if (numbers[j] < numbers[j-1])
          {
              count += 2;
              dir = -1; // start high, down to low
          }
      }
      else
      {
          if (dir == -1 && numbers[j] > numbers[j-1])
          {
              count += 1;
              dir = 1; // up to high
          }
          else if (dir == 1 && numbers[j] < numbers[j-1])
          {
              count += 1;
              dir = -1; // down to low
          }
          else 
          {
              // sequence broken
              if (count > maxCount)
              {
                  maxCount = count;
              }
              count = 0;
              dir = 0;
          }
      }
  }
  // final check after loop is done
  if (count > maxCount)
  {
      maxCount = count;
  }
  return maxCount;
}
```

And some test cases with results based on my understanding of the question and some assumptions.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{

    int[] nums = { 1};            // base case == 0
    int[] nums2 = { 2, 1 };       // even case == 2
    int[] nums3 = { 1, 2, 1 };    // odd case == 3
    int[] nums4 = { 2, 1, 2 };    // flipped starting == 3
    int[] nums5 = { 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1 }; // broken seqeuence == 4
    int[] nums6 = { 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1 }; // long sequence == 14
    Console.WriteLine(max_alternate(nums));
    Console.WriteLine(max_alternate(nums2));
    Console.WriteLine(max_alternate(nums3));
    Console.WriteLine(max_alternate(nums4));
    Console.WriteLine(max_alternate(nums5));
    Console.WriteLine(max_alternate(nums6));
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are probably a lot of ways to approach this, but here is one option:

```
var numbers = new int[] { 7,1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1 };
int maxCount = 0;
for (int j = 0; j+1 < numbers.Length; j++)
{
    int count = 0;
    if (numbers[j] < numbers[j+1])
    {
        count += 2;
        for (int i = j+2; i+1 < numbers.Length; i += 2)
        {
            if (numbers[i] < numbers[i + 1] )
            {
                count += 2;
            }
            else
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    if (maxCount < count)
    {
        maxCount = count;
    }
}
Console.WriteLine(maxCount);
Console.ReadLine();
```

This solution assumes that you want a sequence of the same two alternating numbers.  If that's not a requirement you could alter the second `if`.

Now that it's written out, it looks more complex than I had imagined in my head... Maybe someone else can come up with a better solution.

Comment: Good point, this just counts the length of the sequence from the beginning.  I'll update the answer to address that.

Comment: What if the input contained an odd number of values in a sequence? (note this is after the clarifications were made)

Comment: It should still work.  You should be able to copy and paste that code into a console app if you want to test with different sequences

Answer (score 0):

Assumes at least 2 elements.

```
int max = 1;
bool expectGreaterThanNext = (numbers[0] > numbers[1]);
int count = 1;

for (var i = 0; i < numbers.Length - 1; i++)
{
    if (numbers[i] == numbers[i + 1] || expectGreaterThanNext && numbers[i] < numbers[i + 1])
    {
        count = 1;
        expectGreaterThanNext = (i != numbers.Length - 1) && !(numbers[i] > numbers[i+1]);
        continue;
    }
    count++;
    expectGreaterThanNext = !expectGreaterThanNext;

    max = Math.Max(count, max);
}
```

Comment: `2, 2, 1, 2, 1` returns 2. I believe it should return 4.

Comment: The equality check would take care of having "no direction". That makes sense.

Answer (score -2):

This works for any integers, it tracks low-hi-low and hi-low-hi just like you asked.

```
int numbers[] = new int[] { 1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,2,2,1,2,1 };

   int count = 0;
   int updownup = 0;
   int downupdown = 0;
   for(int x = 0;x<=numbers.Length;x++)
   {
      if(x<numbers.Length - 2)
      {
         if(numbers[x]<numbers[x+1])
         {
          if(numbers[x+1]>numbers[x+2])
           {
           downupdown++; 
            }
         }

    }
}
count = 0;
for(x=0;x<=numbers.Length;x++)
{
  if(x<numbers.Length - 2)
  {
    if(numbers[x]>numbers[x+1]
    {
     if(numbers[x+1]<numbers[x+2])
     {
        updownup++;
        }
    }
    }

}
```

Comment: This isn't C#, which isn't a big deal, but it doesn't produce the correct result either.